# Extra exception being thrown

Tags: c#, exception

Here is a weird scenario that I cannot figure out in C#:

```
try
{
    Call to database.
    If results from database are empty
          throw new Exception("No results");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Equals("No results"))
        throw;
    else
        throw new Exception("Exception from database");
}
```

By right the output should be : `Exception ("No results")`

However at the moment, it keeps throwing 2 Exceptions, i.e. `Exception("No results")` and `Exception("Exception from database")`.

Updates: I tried throwing the 'ex' as an inner exception, hence '`throw new Exception("Exception from database", ex)`'. Turns out that ex is actually '`Exception("No results")`.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Thanks!

PS: Tweaked the above a bit. Hope its clearer now. Its 'throw' not 'return'. Apologies for wrong use of terms.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Exceptions dont return and there is no way 2 can be thrown at the same time on the same thread.

Comment: You can't have 2 exceptions 'returned'. Please give a better description. Post the surrounding catch where you observe this.

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? How can you have 2 exceptions?

Comment: A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would help here...

Comment: I ran your code and it only goes in `if` and not in `else` case. So i see no two exceptions being 'thrown" (Its `thrown` not "returned". Its written in code `throw Exception`).

Comment: Guys, I tweaked the above post a bit. Hope is clearer now. Thanks

Comment: Mine keeps going into if, and also else. No idea why..

Comment: `if and also else`. How can it defy the very logic of `if-else` case

Comment: Clean and rebuild your solution (check if everything is compiled with Build Manager)

Comment: Ok, looking again: when you **debug** your program, you will see the same exception twice - once when you `catch(Exception ex)`, and again after `throw;`. Is this the issue?

Comment: Hi @Kobi, nop. I see the exception 1. When it goes into 'if', hence 'throw'. Right after that, 2. it goes into 'else', hence 'throw ex'. Those are the 2 instances where exception was thrown.

Comment: You're obviously missing something, Dude. Something you're not telling us :) SUGGESTION: single-step through the debugger.  Keep track of the stack at all times.  Keep track of the thread ID at all times.

Comment: @juniordeveloper87 - have you figured out what was going wrong?

Comment: Most likely: 2 exceptions are thrown _in sequence_ and the VS debugger comes up twice.

Answer (score 1):

You have exception when calling to database (or when processing results from database).

BTW if you don't find some data in database it is rarely exceptional situation. Just return null or empty collection.

```
Foo GetFooById(int id)
{
   try
   {
       Call to database.
       If results from database are empty
          return null;
   }
   catch(SqlException ex)
   {   
      throw new MyDataAccessException("Cannot find foo", ex);
   }
}
```

And another advise - do not use exceptions for flow control.

Comment: Hi, nop. Database call was ok, when I tried it in debug mode.

Comment: Maybe you have NullReferenceExeption, IndexOutOfRangeException, cating exception, or some other exception. Reason could be in your database results processing code. Don't swallow your exception. Provide original exception when creating new one, as in my code above.

Comment: Yeah good advice, I was working on someone else's code, who used exceptions for flow control. By the way, as a side question, I also tried creating custom exception, with the original exception as the inner exception of the custom one. However, once it goes through WCF, inner exception disappears. Is this the correct behaviour of WCF?

Comment: @juniordeveloper87 yes, WCF exceptions passed as SOAP fault message and you have FaultException on client. If you want to pass something more interesting, look at generic `FaultException<T>`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure from your code snippet, but it sounds like the reason you seem to have "two" exceptions is probably that you're re-throwing the original one.

Take a look at this link for the difference in C# between "throw ex" (the usual case) and "throw":

http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2007/08/20/Difference-between-quotthrowquot-and-quotthrow-exquot-in-.NET.aspx

Comment: Hi, No its not due to throw ex or throw. I tried both, and the behaviour is the same. 2 exceptions are still thrown.